# Why programmatic selection of multiple rows from DataGridView do not highlight rows

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I try to programatically select multiple rows in `DataGridView` control.
I do this in this way:

```
dgvMain[0, 6].Selected = true;
dgvMain[0, 9].Selected = true;
```

Technically it works because

```
dgvMain.SelectedRows;
```

returns correct values.

Unfortunatelly the selected rows are not highlighted in the GUI.
This problem disappear when

```
dgvMain.MultiSelect = false
```

I have set `SelectionMode` property to `FullRowSelect`.
I tried all method like: `Invalidate`, `Refresh`, `RefreshEdit`,
but without success.

Any ideas why this does not work as expected?

Comment: What happens when you set `dgvMain.Rows[6].Selected = true` and `dgvMain.Rows[9].Selected = true` instead of individual cells?

Comment: What row are highlighted after your code? Maybe some other part of code overwrite your new selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. The main problem was that I tried to select the row before displaying the control. This problem is described here: http://psworld.pl/Programming/DataGridViewBugs